# How to run multiple UPDATE in single SQL statement without removing uniqueness validation?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

A `book` `has_many` `pages`. Pages have attribute `page_no`. I want to addPageAt (z) between any two pages (x, y) of the book and to do that I have to first update all pages of the book from y to book.pages.count and then create->save page(z).

Here's the SQL for single run update:

```
sql = "update pages set page_no = page_no+1 where book_id =" + (@book.id).to_s + " and page_no >" + (@addPageAt - 1).to_s
records_arraty = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

It works! But to do that I had to remove the following validations from `pages` table:

```
validates :book_id, presence: true, on: :save
validates :page_no, presence: true, uniqueness: true, on: :save

validates_uniqueness_of :page_no, :scope => :book_id
```

I want to keep these validations, particularly the third one, in place. How to do that?

Comment: Do you want Rails equivalent sql code ?

Comment: Well it wouldn't hurt I guess, but so far I've been writing SQL directly on my controller/action. What would be better?

Comment: :( No..No.. Use ORM as far as you can.. Not direct sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to either:

1. Use a [SERIALIZABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/transaction-iso.html) Transaction when running Gordon's SQLs above (and have the Caller expect failures (in case someone else attempted a conflicting transaction) and thereby loop to retry the transaction.

OR

2. Run both UPDATEs in a single SQL statement like this:

   ```
   "WITH a
   AS (
     UPDATE pages
     SET page_no = - (page_no + 1)
     WHERE book_id = " + (@book.id).to_s + "
       AND page_no > " + (@addPageAt - 1).to_s + "
     RETURNING *
   ), b AS (
     UPDATE pages
     SET page_no = - page_no
     WHERE book_id = " + (@book.id).to_s + " 
       AND page_no < 0
     RETURNING *
   )
   SELECT 1
   FROM a, b
   LIMIT 1;"
   ```

Answer (score 1):

One method is two separate updates:

```
update pages
    set page_no = - (page_no + 1)
    where book_id = " + (@book.id).to_s + " and page_no >" + (@addPageAt - 1).to_s;

update pages
    set page_no = - page_no
    where where book_id = " + (@book.id).to_s " and page_no < 0);
```

You can do this inside a single transaction, so the negative page numbers are never visible.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding `ORDER BY page_no DESC` to the update query. There will be no duplicate `page_no` when working from the last to the fist one.